# Select rows that don't have a day with few hours

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I have a table with a date column. I want to retrieve records that don't belong to hour 7,8,9 of sunday, hours 8,9,10 of monday and so on. How do i do this.

If I use an "and" clause with "not in" then all the rows disappear not just for the hours.

```
select * from xyz
where (EXTRACT(dow from created) not in (0)
and    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created) not in (8,9,10))
```

Then all rows for sunday are gone.

Comment: Could you clarify "and so on"?

Comment: "date columns" don't have hours. Please clarify. Add your table definition (`\d tbl` in psql) and your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a [`timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) column:

```
SELECT *
FROM   xyz
WHERE  CASE EXTRACT(dow FROM created)
         WHEN 0 THEN EXTRACT(h FROM created) NOT IN (7,8,9)
         WHEN 1 THEN EXTRACT(h FROM created) NOT IN (8,9,10)
         -- other day ...
         ELSE TRUE  -- remaining days pass as a whole
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from xyz
where
    (
        EXTRACT(dow from created) = 0
        and
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created) not in (7,8,9)
    )
    or
    (
        EXTRACT(dow from created) = 1
        and
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created) not in (8,9,10)
    )
    or extract(dow from created) in (2,3,4,5,6)
```